# Using the string matched by '%' from a pattern rule in pattern matching functions

Tags: makefile

I have two sets of files `$(Xs)` and `$(Ys)`. Each `.x` file depends on an arbitrary number of `.y` files based on its name. For each `<name>.x` file I have a number of `<name>_*.y` files.

I can write individual rules for the `.x` files and use a function to compute the dependencies for it.

```
.PHONY: build
Xs = a.x b.x
Ys = a_1.y a_2.y b_1.y b_2.y

build: $(Xs)

a.x: $(filter a%,$(Ys))             
    @echo $@" with dependencies: "$+

b.x: $(filter b%,$(Ys))             
    @echo $@" with dependencies: "$+

%.y:
    @echo "y : "$@
```

... or I could write a pattern rule for all `.x` files and enumerate the dependencies

```
$(Xs) : %.x : %_1.y %_2.y
    @echo $@" with dependencies: "$+
```

But can I do both at the same time? I don't know how to get the string matched by `%` in the rule and use it in `$(filter)`.

```
$(Xs) : %.x : $(filter ???,$(Ys))
    @echo $@" with dependencies: "$+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) and a [Canned Recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) (needed to work around the double use of <kbd>%</kbd> in `filter` and the static pattern rule's prereq list.

```
.PHONY: build
Xs = a.x b.x
Ys = a_1.y a_2.y b_1.y b_2.y

build: $(Xs)

%.y:
    @echo 'y : $@'

define yf
    $(filter $(1)_%.y,$(Ys))
endef

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(Xs) : %.x : $$(call yf,%)
    @echo '$@ with dependencies: $+'
```